# How do I enable java linter when I am using VSCode? It isn't working now

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out how to enable the linter (red error underline) whenever I use the code editor. So far I have tried enabling other Java linter extensions and re-installing vscode, but no luck. I am currently running v1.28, and my only extensions are the ones in the Java Extension pack.

Side Note:
I encountered is a popup saying "Java runtime could not be located", prompting me to install to install the jdk. I'm not very experienced with vscode and java so I am not sure if this is the error. If anyone has any potential solutions please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should install jdk on your os , and if you done before , set path in your environment variables.
Make sure the jvm works correctly on your os after installing with this command :

`Java -version`

Download jdk from here :
`https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html`